# ¿Cómo paso un valor select de un botón que está en otra página?

Tags: javascript, html5

Quisiera saber como podría pasar por medio de un evento click de botón un valor option a un select que está en otra página. El contexto es que digamos tengo un catálogo de productos y en "pedir ahora" quisiera que me cargue una página de formulario pero con el nombre de este producto ya seleccionado.

Answer (score 2):

Podrías utilizar sessionStorage para guardar el valor que tu necesitas recuperar en la siguiente vista

```
let select = document.getElementById('selectProducts');

function sendData() {
   var selectedOption = select.options[select.selectedIndex];
   sessionStorage.setItem('value-select',selectedOption.value)
}
```

Y en la siguiente vista obtenemos el valor con la función getItem() de sessionStorage

```
let value = sessionStorage.getItem('value-select');
```

Espero que te funcione.